# Sankey diagram on maps

Tags: qgis, python, geometry-generator

I want to create sankey diagrams (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram) from date like:

```
zipcodepoly1 zipcodepoly2 value
12345        45789        250000,00
....
```

I have polygons with attributes for the zipcodes and I have the values.

It seems that it should be possible with geoplot.sankey? But I have to define a line layer.

It should also be possible with geometry generator in qgis. Any Hints?
How to create Sankey diagrams on a map in QGIS or with Python?

Because of the inspiration from https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/ I create a flowmap that is nearley a sankey. I am not realy satisfied by the scale but as first effort it is OK.

[image: flow map 1]

Comment: Definitely, a nice question that deserves its attention. However, can you please elucidate the efforts you have done and tell us what have you tried by so far? Do you have some ideas on how to achieve the desired output? Have you seen some other threads or articles on this topic? What about GeoPandas and Geoplot? Have you seen this https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/gallery/plot_dc_street_network.html?

Comment: what is a sankey diagram?

Comment: Where do you want it? On a print layout?

Comment: I need to have it on a map. More or less as print layout. I want to include it in a report. So the result as *.jpg or *.png would be fine.

Comment: I dont understand what you want. Can you add a drawing or something to illustrate. Seems you can create them using matplotlib (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/sankey_api.html)